# How to dismiss Bottomsheet on Click in ViewHolder RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to dismiss my BottomSheet on Click of cardView in BottomSheet

Here is my code of onBindViewHolder

```
 class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private TextView num_name;
        private TextView call_type;
        private TextView call_duration;
        public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            num_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_number);
            call_type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_type_txt);
            call_duration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_duration_txt);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        private void setData(String name_num, String call_typ, String call_dur){
            num_name.setText(name_num);
            call_type.setText(call_typ);
            call_duration.setText(call_dur);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BottomSheetCall bottomSheetCall = new BottomSheetCall();
            bottomSheetCall.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

I getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment BottomSheetCall{31fd510 (dbba722a-e3f4-46d4-826c-f31cbc221bd6)} not associated with a fragment manager.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireFragmentManager(Fragment.java:910)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:245)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:202)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment.dismiss(BottomSheetDialogFragment.java:47)
        at com.bizcure.waessentials.ui.main.CallAdapter$1.onClick(CallAdapter.java:53)
```

onClick I want to dismiss Bottomsheet and backto Activity.

Thank you in advance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have done here will not work as you expect it to be :-

```
BottomSheetCall bottomSheetCall = new BottomSheetCall();
bottomSheetCall.dismiss();
```

Here you are creating a new `bottomSheet` Object so using `dismiss()` on this object will not work. Instead you need a interface which will provide you a callback to your bottomShett Fragment where you have setup your recyclerView. And in that Callback you need to call simply call BottomSheet inbuild method `dismiss()`. Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31671289/12768366) on S.O which shows how you can create that interface which will provide you callback to your Fragment.

Comment: as you said I did, but still getting same error, please check code, I edited question

Comment: Again you are doing the same thing. The link in the answer clearly shows how you can get item click callback to your fragment/Activity. You need to call `dismiss()` in your fragment itself. Also no need to do this `BottomSheetCall bottomSheetCall = new BottomSheetCall();` which you have done in your onClickListener. You just need to call `dismiss()` in your fragment itself whenever the `itemClickListener` has been Called.

Comment: Now I finally did, Thanks

Comment: Please upvote the answer. If it dd help you so that others can find it easily.

Comment: I am new on StackOverflow and I have 5 reputation score, to upvote answer I need 15 reputation score, after getting 15 in future I will do. Thanks a lot

Comment: No worries. Glad to help buddy !